# How to set correct privileges to use Python Azure SDK for Graph?

Tags: python, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to add a reply_url programmatically to an Azure app registration, but I receive an `GraphErrorException: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation`.

Problem is I don't understand which privileges my app registration needs.

Basically I am using the credentials of the app registration to change its own reply_urls.

The privileges set are `User.Read` and `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy`. Both granted.

Which one am I missing? And how can I find out?

This is the SDK I am using: [azure-graphrbac==0.61.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-graphrbac/?view=azure-python)

My code looks like this:

```
class GraphClient:
    def __init__(self, client_id, client_secret, tenant_id, object_id):
        self._credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
            client_id=client_id,
            secret=client_secret,
            tenant=tenant_id,
            resource="https://graph.windows.net"
        )
        self._graph_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(
            credentials=self._credentials,
            tenant_id=tenant_id
        )
        self._application = self._graph_client.applications.get(object_id)

    def get_reply_urls(self) -> List[str]:
        return self._application.reply_urls

    def add_reply_url(self, reply_url) -> None:
        reply_urls: list = self.get_reply_urls()
        self._graph_client.applications.patch(
            self._application.app_id,
            ApplicationUpdateParameters(
                reply_urls=[
                    *reply_urls,
                    reply_url]
            )
        )
```

EDIT: Added permissions screenshot
[image]

Comment: Hi, could you please share a screenshot of the permissions which you added(the "API permmissions" tab of your azure app registration) ?

Comment: Please refer to the solution I provided below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use microsoft graph, the resource should be: `https://graph.microsoft.com`

If use azure ad graph, the resource should be: `https://graph.windows.net`

According to your code, the resource is `https://graph.windows.net`, so it request azure ad graph api in the backend. **So we need to add the permissions of azure ad graph but not microsoft graph.**

The screenshot you provided shows you added the permission `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` of microsoft graph but not azure ad graph. So please remove it and add the same permission which belongs to azure ad graph.
[image]

[image]

Then don't forget to grant admin consent for it.

[image]

Hope it helps~

Comment: What if I just change the resource to use Microsoft Graph correctly? I tried it and get a `azure.graphrbac.models.graph_error_py3.GraphErrorException: Your access token has expired. Please renew it before submitting the request.` error.

Comment: @MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst It seems the resource should be `https://graph.windows.net` when we use this python sdk. I don't know if we can change the resource, I think the best way is change the permission but not change the resource.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Now I get another one `azure.graphrbac.models.graph_error_py3.GraphErrorException: Specified HTTP method is not allowed for the request target.` Different topic, I guess.

Comment: @MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst Could you please create another post for the new issue and provide details of it (such as which sdk you use in your code), I will try to investigate it.

Comment: Done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61630690/how-to-patch-an-existing-application-using-python-azure-sdk-and-graph