# How to patch an existing application using Python Azure SDK and Graph?

Tags: python, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to add a reply_url programmatically to an Azure app registration, but I receive an `azure.graphrbac.models.graph_error_py3.GraphErrorException: Specified HTTP method is not allowed for the request target.`

It fails when I try to update an existing application with new `reply_urls`.

SDK I am using is: [azure-graphrbac==0.61.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-graphrbac/?view=azure-python)

My code:

```py
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient
from azure.graphrbac.models import ApplicationUpdateParameters

class GraphClient:
    def __init__(self, client_id, client_secret, tenant_id, object_id):
        self._credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
            client_id=client_id,
            secret=client_secret,
            tenant=tenant_id,
            resource="https://graph.windows.net"
        )
        self._graph_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(
            credentials=self._credentials,
            tenant_id=tenant_id
        )
        self._object_id = object_id
        self._application = self._graph_client.applications.get(self._object_id)

    def get_reply_urls(self) -> List[str]:
        return self._application.reply_urls

    def add_reply_url(self, reply_url) -> None:
        reply_urls: list = self.get_reply_urls()
        self._graph_client.applications.patch(
            self._object_id,
            ApplicationUpdateParameters(
                reply_urls=[
                    *reply_urls,
                    reply_url]
            )
        )
```

Comment: May I know the version of your python ?

Comment: @HuryShen Python 3.6.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could not reproduce your issue, use the same version of `azure-graphrbac`, I test your code on my side, it works fine.

```
testclient = GraphClient(client_id = "xxxxx",client_secret = "xxxxx", tenant_id = "xxxxx", object_id = "xxxxx")
testclient.add_reply_url(reply_url = "http://localhost:8085")
```

[image]

Check in the portal:

[image]

---

Also, I test the sdk directly, both work.

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient
from azure.graphrbac.models import ApplicationUpdateParameters

_credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
            client_id="xxxxx",
            secret="xxxxx",
            tenant="xxxxx",
            resource="https://graph.windows.net"
        )
_graph_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(
            credentials=_credentials,
            tenant_id="xxxxx"
        )
app = _graph_client.applications.patch(
    application_object_id = "xxxxx",
    parameters = ApplicationUpdateParameters(reply_urls = ["http://localhost:8080","http://localhost:8081"])                            
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

Update call looks good however it depends on a legacy API (AAD Graph) and tools. It's strongly recommended to move to [MS Graph which supports almost all Azure AD Graph operations and will fully support them all in a future](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/migrate-azure-ad-graph-overview). [Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-1.0#methods) being one of them.

You can use [Requests-OAuthlib](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-auth#request-oauthlib-sample_requestspy) or [Microsoft Graph Python Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python-core#microsoft-graph-python-client-library) for this.